# Shifting content left Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Has anyone had a problem with Material UI dropdown Select and Modals shift the content to the left? I tried to give it position: absolute I also tried to give the MenuItems position: absolute but the content was still shifted.

Comment: Are you using [CssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/style/css-baseline/)?

Comment: No I don't but I have normalizsed the CSS. I tried add it now but there was no change.

Comment: The main case where I have seen something like this is when the main window has a scroll bar. Opening a Modal (which Select uses for showing options), causes the scroll bar to temporarily disappear which can case a slight shift in content depending on the overall layout approach. Is this your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about this here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10000

There are a number of related issues referenced there as well. There are different ways of fixing it depending on how the main window elements under the modal are being positioned.

Comment: Thank you :) I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In my React app, this worked for me.

```
<body style="overflow-y: scroll;">
```

```
    //index.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
       </head>
       <body style="overflow-y: scroll;">
         <noscript>
         </noscript>
         <div id="root"></div>
         <script></script>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had this issue. For me, adding `overflow-y: scroll` just made the extra space on the right be there all the time if the select element was present. I investigated in Devtools. For some reason clicking on the select was adding `padding-right: 15px` to the body. I added the following and that fixed it.

```
body {
   padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Had to do the same for the header.